# What is a Householder reflection?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

In an article I was looking at it states given a non-zero vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can transform by a linear transformation, for example Householder reflection, to a vector of the form 
$(\delta, 0, .., 0)^T$ for some $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$. It gives as a reference for the Household reflection, a large book, and I'm struggling to find the description. I would appreciate if someone could explain me what this is. thank you.

Comment: you say "non-vector"  what does that mean? What is $\delta$ intended to mean?

Comment: typo corrected. thank you

Comment: check Wikipedia